# how to deploy a single file using capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano3

In previous versions of Capistrano, there used to be a task/ command via which i could easily deploy just one file from my local to the server, I didn't need to do the steps like first commit the changes, then push it to git repo and then deploy the whole repo.

With latest version 3 I can't find the similar command.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same feature that existed in Capistrano 2.
Reiknistofa made a gem. You should have a look to https://github.com/Reiknistofa/capistrano-upload